# let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq \frac {n^2}{2^n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Then

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\leq \frac {n^2}{2^n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. Then

> > (a). The sequence $(a_n)$ may be unbounded.
> >
> > (b). The sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded but may not converge.
> >
> > (c). The sequence $(a_n)$ has exactly two limit points.
> >
> > (d). The sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent.

**My work**

$$|a_n|-|a_{n+1}|\leq |a_n-a_{n+1}|\leq \frac {n^2}{2^n}$$

$$|a_n|\leq |a_{n+1}|+\frac {n^2}{2^n}$$

So, we can conclude that the sequence is either increasing or decreasing. So, sequece may be unbouded. Is it correct?

Comment: You might want to look at the series $\sum_n { n^2 \over 2^n}$.

Comment: its cgs by root test. but what we are going to do with the series?@copper.hat

Comment: Show that the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: $|a_n-a_m| \le |a_n-a_{n-1}| +| a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}| + \cdots +|a_{m+1}-a_m|$.

Comment: thank you so much.. it is cauchy so it is converges..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
|a_{n}-a_m|&\leq |a_n-a_{n+1}|+|a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}|+\ldots+|a_{m-1}-a_m|\\
&\leq \frac{n^2}{2^n}+\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{n+1}}+\ldots+\frac{m^2}{2^m}\\
&=\frac{n^2}{2^n}\left\{1+\frac{(1+\frac 1 n)^2}{2^{n}}+\ldots+\frac{(1+\frac {1}{m-n})^2}{2^{m-n}}\right\}\\
&\to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty
\end{align}

Therefore, the sequence is cauchy, so that its converges.

Answer (score 0):

Using copper.hat's hint, for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
|a_n-a_m| \le \sum_{i=m}^{n-1}\frac{i^2}{2^i}
$$
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
You have noticed that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^2}{2^i}$$
converges. 
This means that the sequence of partial sums:
$$
A_N=\sum_{i=1}^{i=N}\frac{i^2}{2^i}
$$
is Cauchy.
Thus there exists $N'\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n \ge N'$:
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\frac{i^2}{2^i}-\sum_{i=1}^{i=m}\frac{i^2}{2^i}\right|=\left| \sum_{i=m+1}^{i=n}\frac{i^2}{2^i}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}
$$
Thus: for $n,m\ge N'$,
$$
|a_{n}-a_m| \le |a_{n}-a_{n+1}| + |a_{n+1}-a_{m+1}|+|a_{m+1}-a_m|< 3\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon
$$